# Two router-outlets with children and name not navigating

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create `router-outlet` with `name`. I'm using two router-outlets, one for main routeing and the other for custom routing of one route children.
I get to RouterNotFoundComponent when I try to navigate to:

```
http://localhost:64413/RouterMain/(RouterMainChild:FirstComponent)
http://localhost:64413/RouterMain/(RouterMainChild:SecundComponent)
```

However the strange thing after it redirect to `RouterNotFoundComponent` when I refresh the page it renders `FirstComponent` inside `NavMenuComponent` as it supposed to be!

app.module.ts:

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      {
        path: 'RouterMain', component: NavMenuComponent
        , children: [
          { path: 'FirstComponent', component: FirstComponent, outlet: 'RouterMainChild' },
          { path: 'SecundComponent', component: SecundComponent, outlet: 'RouterMainChild' }
        ]
      },
      { path: '**', component: RouterNotFoundComponent }

    ]
    ),
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `
    <button routerLink="/RouterMain"> Router Main</button>
  `,
})
export class HomeComponent {
}
```

nav-menu.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ThemePalette } from '@angular/material/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-menu',
  templateUrl: './nav-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-menu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent {


  navLinks: any[];
  activeLink: any;

  constructor(private router: Router) {

    this.navLinks = [
      {
        label: 'FirstComponent',
        link: './(RouterMainChild:FirstComponent)',
        index: 0
      }, {
        label: 'SecundComponent',
        link: './(RouterMainChild:SecundComponent)',
        index: 1
      },
    ];

    this.activeLink = this.navLinks[0].link;

  }
}
```

nav-menu.component.html

```
  <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
     <a mat-tab-link
       *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
       [routerLink]="link.link"
       (click)="activeLink = link.link"
       [active]="activeLink == link.link">
       {{link.label}}
    </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet name="RouterMainChild"></router-outlet>
```

Comment: try change to this: link: './RouterMainChild/SecundComponent', or without point:  link: '/RouterMainChild/SecundComponent',

Comment: @TomaszVizaint same result it navigates to RouterNotFoundComponent

Comment: try doing this ```link: '/FirstComponent'``` in the `nav-menu.component.ts` and the same for the other link

Comment: @Kardon63 Tried both  `link: '/FirstComponent' ` and `link: './FirstComponent' ` same result it navigates to RouterNotFoundComponent

Comment: Router links are searched in order, and the first match is found. So starting with '' is always going to navigate there, unless you give it the property `pathMatch: 'full'`

Comment: @iamaword I've added `pathMatch: 'full'` to HomeComponent same result first it navigates to RouterNotFoundComponent and after refresh it work just fine

Answer (score 0):

If someone experiencing the same issue, I found a way to fix it:

change this line in `nav-menu.component.html` :

```
   [routerLink]="link.link"
```

To:

```
 [routerLink]="['./', { outlets: { RouterMainChild: link.link } }]"
```

And in `nav-menu.component.ts` the navLinks will look like:

```
this.navLinks = [
  {
    label: 'FirstComponent',
    link: 'FirstComponent',
    index: 0
  }, {
    label: 'SecundComponent',
    link: 'SecundComponent',
    index: 1
  },
];
```

And if you want the selection of tabs to be based on the current path add:

```
  this.router.events.subscribe((res) => {
  this.activeLink = this.navLinks.find(tab => tab.link == this.router.url.substring(this.router.url.indexOf(':') + 1, this.router.url.length - 1)).link;
});
```

And if you want to track the back and forward buttons:

```
 router.events
  .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
    if (event.navigationTrigger === 'popstate') {
        this.activeLink = this.navLinks.find(tab => tab.link == event.url.substring(this.router.url.indexOf(':') + 1, event.url.length - 1)).link;
    } 
  });
```